# Does Windows Server 2016 RRAS support NAT reflection/loopback?

Tags: nat, windows-server-2016, port-forwarding, rras

I have a home server running Windows Server 2016 Datacenter acting as the NAT on the network. On the same server I'm using Hyper-V to host various services (game servers, GitLab, Plex, etc). I'm using Routing and Remote Access to forward ports to the correct virtual machines.

From outside the network, everything works perfectly. Inside the network, me and other users that want to connect to specific servers need to know the ip address assigned to the server vs using a domain name I have through Cloudflare.

I've been researching all day on this, does RRAS not support this at all?

Or, as an alternate solution, is there a way for me to apply port forwarding rules on my internal network using a VM? Ie, connect to 192.168.1.5 at tcp port 58, redirect to 192.168.1.4 at tcp port 25565.

Comment: So can your friends access your game server externally from pub.lic.ip.add:987 ?

Comment: @jstuart-tech Yes, friends can access the game server from the external network using external ip or the domain from cloudflare no problem. It's only when you try doing the same from inside the NAT (pub.lic.ip.add when behind NAT) that it doesn't work.

Comment: Ah ok. I understand what you mean now.

Comment: I can't imagine why you get 2 downvotes. Maybe those who think you can only post high-level questions? If this site is only for "glamour savvy people" maybe it should be noted on the use rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for something called Hairpin NAT that MS RRAS doesn't seem to support unfortunately

Comment: Is there something I can do as a workaround using a vm and messing with dns? Ie, setup local dns server, point to vm that forwards to correct port

Comment: I would personally replace your RRAS server with a PFSense VM. That will allow you to do what you want to do.

Comment: Alright, marking your response as the answer. Thanks for the assistance!